# Is it possible to install macOS in a Windows machine?

Tags: macos, windows, install, virtualization

I recently moved to a company which doesn't use Mac laptops. It's a pain to switch back to Windows after using a Mac for 10+ years.

Just  wondering if it's possible to install macOS in a Windows machine?

Comment: It‘s called a hackintosh. But if your company allows you to install another OS on a company-provided machine doesn‘t it also allow you to get a Mac directly?

Comment: A virtual machine?

Comment: Note that the MacOS license is not valid for installing on non-Apple hardware.  Your company may not like if you do that anyway.

Comment: Technically it is possible, Legally not so much, politically not so much

Comment: If a company uses windows rather than macs it is not because of the hsrdware. It is because of the os and the tools that surround it.  Thus it is windows you must use.

Comment: i dont think its possible to move to mac as @Mark said its because their image works only with windows.